# How to interpret nested dictionary list comprehension with conditionals in Python 3

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm in a class for Python right now and am having a hard time understanding list / set / dictionary comprehension. I'm hoping someone can help me understand an answer I've been provided, and can maybe help me understand the underlying rules that make up this answer, as well as point me to some resources so I can gain some better intuition about these rules.

The question is as follows:

> The school registrar uses a `dict`, where keys are courses (ie. `'PHYS12'`, `'PHYS13'`) and its associated value is a `set` of `2-tuples`. Each `tuple` has a student name, and a letter grade (potentially followed by +/-. A sample registrar looks like this:

```
db = {'PHYS12': {('Bob', 'A'), ('David', 'C'), ('Carol', 'B')}, 'PHYS13': {('Bob',
'B'), ('Alice', 'A')}}
```

> We can also have the following `dict` which associates grades with grade points:

```
SCHOOL = {'A+': 4.0, 'A': 4.0, 'A-': 3.7,
 'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0, 'B-': 2.7,
 'C+': 2.3, 'C': 2.0, 'C-': 1.7,
 'D+': 1.3, 'D': 1.0, 'D-': 0.7,
 'F' : 0.0}
```

> Given this information, define a function: `gpa_ex` which takes in an `int` param, and returns a `dict`, where the keys are course names and the values are `lists` of student names, sorted decreasing by grade, whose grade equals or exceeds the `gpa` parameter. If the `gpa` of multiple students is the same, the students appear in ascending alphabetical order. For instance, if we call `gpa_ex(2.7)`, it would return:

```
{'PHYS12': ['Bob', 'Carol'], 'PHYS13': ['Alice', 'Bob']}
```

So, I understand how to do this by iterating over `db.items()`, then over the tuple, and then comparing the `grade` to the `gpa` passed in. My issue is with the answer provided which is as follows:

```
return {c: [s for _,s in sorted((-SCHOOL[g],s) for (s,g) in grades if SCHOOL[g] >= gpa)] for c,grades in db.items()}
```

Can anyone help me break this answer down, and explain to me what is happening? Given that we've only gone over basic list comprehension, ie. `[value for value in list]`, I'm having a really really hard time understanding what syntax is legal, what the rules are for that syntax (ie. when can I use a variable, when can I not), and just how to even construct something like this. Mostly, what is the thought process behind constructing it? If I have a working normal looping solution, how would I apply that to build this comprehension out?

Comment: it's a dictionary comprehension, using values made with a list comprehension with transformations & conditions. The `sorted` bit is used to sort according to opposite mark then second term (tiebreaker), keep only scores > gpa ... yeah. Complex enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems we have a list comprehension embedded inside the dict comprehension. So in other words, we have a dict of lists that looks like

```
list_comprehension = [s for _,s in sorted((-SCHOOL[g],s) for (s,g) in grades if SCHOOL[g] >= gpa)]
{c:[list_comprehension] for c,grades in db.items()}
```

This much is pretty straightforward. Now, let's look at the `[something]`:

```
[s for _,s in sorted((-SCHOOL[g],s) for (s,g) in grades if SCHOOL[g] >= gpa)]
```

which is itself a list comprehension of a tuple comprehension:

```
tuple_comprehension = ((-SCHOOL[g], s) for (s,g) in grades if SCHOOL[g] >= gpa)
[s for s in sorted(tuple_comprehension)]
```

So let's look at the `tuple_comprehension`:

```
((-SCHOOL[g], s) for (s,g) in grades if SCHOOL[g] >= gpa)
```

The conditional statement here means that `(-SCHOOL[g], s)` is only added to the output *if* `SCHOOL[g] >= gpa` evaluates to `True`. Otherwise that element is skipped.

---

So overall, the statement is

```
return {c:                   # key:value, where the value is a list comprehension:
    [s for _,s in            # list comprehension, where the source-list is...
        sorted(              # ...the sorted version of the comprehension:
            (-SCHOOL[g],s) for (s,g) in grades if SCHOOL[g] >= gpa   comprehension
        )
     ]                       # end list comprehension
for c,grades in db.items()}  # end dict comprehension
```

For methods like `sorted()` which can take an arbitrary number of variables, you can pass in a comprehension without the square-brackets or circle-brackets you'd normally need. Above, I called that a "tuple comprehension", though that's not really correct terminology.

As far as "when do you define a variable in a list comprehension": it's in the `for` clause, when you're defining what is being iterated through. Then, you can use those variables in both the *definition* (the object/key-value pair at the beginning to add) or the *condition* (the `if` statement at the end) For example, in

```
... for (s,g) in grades ...
```

`s` and `g` are defined here and can be used anywhere else in this comprehension (or any other comprehensions *nested inside of it*).

In your example overall, `vc` and `grades` are defined in the outer dict comprehension, and are used within the *definition*, which includes nested list comprehensions. Then, `_` and `s` are defined in the inner list comprehension, and are used in the *definition* `s` (that is, `_` is ignored). And finally, `g` and another `s` (no relation to the one defined outside) are defined in the innermost comprehension, and are used in both the *definition* `(-SCHOOL[g], s)` and *condition* (`if SCHOOL[g] >= gpa`).

Answer (score 2):

@GreenCloakGuy already gave a [great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56048024/1941241) of what the answer code does. I'll try to explain how you would get from a piece of code using for loops and intermediate variables down to such a comprehension construct.

> This will be a lengthy one

Without using comprehensions, you'd have to write something like the following to get to the question's desired outcome:

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    result = {}

    for className, grades in db.items():
        scores = []

        for studentName, gradeLetter in grades:
            score = SCHOOL[gradeLetter]

            if score >= gpa:
                scores.append((-score, studentName))

        sortedScores = sorted(scores)

        result[className] = []

        for _, studentName in sortedScores:
            result[className].append(studentName)

    return result
```

Comprehensions are a great tool to shorten code, so let's see if we can use that to condense this down a bit.

As a first step, we can use a list comprehension to simplify the building of `result[className]`:

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    result = {}

    for className, grades in db.items():
        scores = []

        for studentName, gradeLetter in grades:
            score = SCHOOL[gradeLetter]

            if score >= gpa:
                scores.append((-score, studentName))

        sortedScores = sorted(scores)

        # result[className] = []
        # 
        # for _, studentName in sortedScores:
        #     result[className].append(studentName)
        result[className] = [studentName for _, studentName in sortedScores]

    return result
```

`sortedScores` is just the result of `sorted(scores)`, we don't need a separate variable for that since we can just do that inline:

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    result = {}

    for className, grades in db.items():
        scores = []

        for studentName, gradeLetter in grades:
            score = SCHOOL[gradeLetter]

            if score >= gpa:
                scores.append((-score, studentName))

        # sortedScores = sorted(scores)
        result[className] = [studentName for _, studentName in sorted(scores)]

    return result
```

Before we turn the creation of `scores` into a comprehension, it's important to note that we need to convert the grade letter "A" into a grade score "4.0" so that it can be sorted. Or actually, "-4.0" so that it's sorted in descending order.

Right now, I've used a separate variable `score` for that. Let's see what happens if we just drop that variable and use `SCHOOL[gradeLetter]` twice:

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    result = {}

    for className, grades in db.items():
        scores = []

        for studentName, gradeLetter in grades:
            # score = SCHOOL[gradeLetter]
            if SCHOOL[gradeLetter] >= gpa:
                scores.append((-SCHOOL[gradeLetter], studentName))

        result[className] = [studentName for _, studentName in sorted(scores)]

    return result
```

That looks like it could be a conditional list comprehension, doesn't it?

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    result = {}

    for className, grades in db.items():
        # scores = []
        # 
        # for studentName, gradeLetter in grades:
        #     if SCHOOL[gradeLetter] >= gpa:
        #         scores.append((-SCHOOL[gradeLetter], studentName))
        scores = [(-SCHOOL[gradeLetter], studentName) for studentName, gradeLetter in grades if SCHOOL[gradeLetter] >= gpa]

        result[className] = [studentName for _, studentName in sorted(scores)]

    return result
```

And, well, it may not be pretty, but there's not really a point in creating a variable if we're only going to use it once, so we can put the creation of `scores` right in that one place we use it:

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    result = {}

    for className, grades in db.items():
        # scores = [(-SCHOOL[gradeLetter], studentName) for studentName, gradeLetter in grades if SCHOOL[gradeLetter] >= gpa]
        result[className] = [studentName for _, studentName in sorted(
            [(-SCHOOL[gradeLetter], studentName) for studentName, gradeLetter in grades if SCHOOL[gradeLetter] >= gpa]
        )]

    return result
```

Although this step is optional, since it is now a function argument to the `sorted()` function, we could potentially drop the `[]` in the comprehension. Instead of a list comprehension, this will create an iterable *generator*. For this particular use case that doesn't make any difference whatsoever, since `sorted()` can deal with those just fine. I personally wouldn't bother, since it saves two characters but creates a bit more overhead, but it's what your teacher provided as the answer:

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    result = {}

    for className, grades in db.items():
        result[className] = [studentName for _, studentName in sorted(
            (-SCHOOL[gradeLetter], studentName) for studentName, gradeLetter in grades if SCHOOL[gradeLetter] >= gpa
        )]

    return result
```

Now that we have condensed it this far, we can see that the creation of the `result` dict can be simplified to a dict comprehension:

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    # result = {}
    # 
    # for className, grades in db.items():
    #     result[className] = [studentName for _, studentName in sorted(
    #         (-SCHOOL[gradeLetter], studentName) for studentName, gradeLetter in grades if SCHOOL[gradeLetter] >= gpa
    #     )]
    result = {
        className: [studentName for _, studentName in sorted(
            (-SCHOOL[gradeLetter], studentName) for studentName, gradeLetter in grades if SCHOOL[gradeLetter] >= gpa
        )] for className, grades in db.items()
    }

    return result
```

And now that we, once again, have created a variable we use only once, we might as well just drop that variable altogether:

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    return {
        className: [studentName for _, studentName in sorted(
            (-SCHOOL[gradeLetter], studentName) for studentName, gradeLetter in grades if SCHOOL[gradeLetter] >= gpa
        )] for className, grades in db.items()
    }
```

If you shorten the variable names to condense it down a bit (something I personally wouldn't do since I like my variable names to tell me something about what they're for), you get back the answer you originally had:

```
def gpa_ex(gpa):
    return {
        c: [s for _, s in sorted(
            (-SCHOOL[g], s) for s, g in grades if SCHOOL[g] >= gpa
        )] for c, grades in db.items()
    }
```

It takes a bit of practice to recognise the situations where creating a list or dict can be reduced to a comprehension. It may not have been immediately apparent that `scores` could be a conditional list comprehension by removing the separate `score` variable and just using `SCHOOL[gradeLetter]` twice. Especially since that is counter-intuitive (we developers don't like repeating ourselves, so if we do the same thing multiple times we tend to stick it in a variable or function so we can re-use it). This is the sort of thing that comes with practice and experience.

Personally, I think this answer goes slightly too far (unless the whole point of the question was to teach you how to use comprehensions). Shorter code is not always better code, always keep maintainability in mind. Just imagine using this code in a real-world application, and two years from now you need to tweak the `gpa_ex` function a bit due to changing business logic (maybe you need to change the sort order, or `>= gpa` needs to become `> gpa`). Which version of this function would you rather be faced with? The shorthand comprehension construct, the fully written-out code I started with, or one of the in-between versions?